# How to send and recover data from a SQL database in Android

Tags: android, sql, database, gps, location

I'm developing an app that gets the location of one cellphone, sends the coordinates to a database and a second cellphone can access that location and display it in a map along with its own location, I already have the code for the first cellphone but I don't know how to send the coordinates to a SQL database and then access them from the other code, I was thinking about using `JDBC` but I don't know if it is going to work with android.
Thank you.

Comment: android uses SQL lite database internally, you will have to find a way to insert and retrieve from that database

Comment: you need a server. php perhaps

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to get a hosting service which supports MySql and PHP. Build a database with PHPMyAdmin, build your PHP api to either post or retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class. You can extend the class and use it to create a database and execute your sql statements. Android already handles the connection to the db.